# Apache Security settings - unsure of where to find in Config file

Tags: apache, security, windows-server-2012-r2

This is my first post under the Apache tag, so not sure if I have posted it in the correct spot.  Apologies if it's not.
We recently had an audit done on our Apache server.  It's running on a Windows Server 2012 R2, and I installed Apache 2.4.27 through WAMP.
The results from the Audit are fairly specific, but I don't know where to go in the Config file to fix these.  My IMIT department has gone through a number of changes and we no longer have someone who can help me, so I'm stuck.

The three areas I need to correct are:
1) MISSING SECURITY HEADERS Recommendation: Implement HTTP security headers in the web applications to prevent exploitation of vulnerabilities. 
2) Recommendation: Make sure that browsable directories do not leak confidential informative or give access to sensitive resources. Additionally, use access restrictions or disable directory indexing for any that do. 
3) The remote web server supports the TRACE and/or TRACK methods. TRACE and TRACK are HTTP methods that are used to debug web server connections. Recommendation: Disable these methods.

I have looked in the config and in various documentation online but the Windows install for Apache seems to be unique, and I don't want to risk screwing up something that breaks the install.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Chris

Comment: Have you found your `httpd.conf`? This is pretty broad. Back things up, implement the suggested changes... For first one, turning on `mod_headers` if not already enabled would be a good start.

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply, and that's my problem - I don't know how to implement the suggested changes, documentation that I can find are for Linux or other non-Windows environments, and the directions that they provide don't work in a Windows environment.  I'll look at enabling mod_headers if it isn't already.

Answer (score 0):

Find **httpd.conf** file. It should be in the **conf** folder in the localization where Apache is installed like for ex:

```
C:/Apache/Apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

If you're not sure where that is - open task manager, find **httpd.exe** and check it's properties.

Then add required configuration there. 
Check out this helpful github:
https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess

You can check your configuration files for syntax errors without starting the server by using apachectl configtest or the -t command line option.